# Filtering product ids

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, stream

As regarding the following question I have completed the code as below.

But I am curious about other effective solutions. I am also curious about if there is any solution that could be applicable by using java stream API.

It is not mandatory to keep records at `int[][]` matrix. Any data structure can be used.

My solution has `O(n)` time complexity. If you have a better to solve the question please share your solution.

For a given retailer "100" function only needs to return 4 because product 1 exists in other retailers.

Thanks.

```
public class InterviewQuestion {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] itemSeller =       { {1, 100},
                                 {2, 200},
                                 {3, 300},
                                 {4, 100},
                                 {1, 200},
                                 {2, 300} };

    int target = 100;

    getUniqueProduct(itemSeller,target);

}

private static void getUniqueProduct(int[][] itemSeller, int target) {


    int count[] = new int[itemSeller.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < itemSeller.length; i++) {
        count[itemSeller[i][0]]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < itemSeller.length; i++) {
        if (target == itemSeller[i][1]) {

            int item = itemSeller[i][0];
            if (count[item] > 1) {
                continue;
            } else
                System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is there any idea for achieving it O(logn) time. I was thinking to achieve it finding similarity to this problem "https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/354854/Facebook-or-Phone-Screen-or-Cut-Wood" .

Answer (score 2):

Your class is `InterviewQuestion`, if it is for an interview, then there's a few other things to consider, in addition to whether or not you get a reasonably efficient solution.  Whilst a bad solution will probably rule you out, a non-optimal solution may be acceptable depending on other factors.

**Seperation of concerns**

Finding the list of unique product items seems like it's a different concern to printing the list out to the console.  Rather than printing the items out directly, it would be better to return the list of items and then print them from the caller.  Not only does this demonstrate that you're thinking about reuse, but it also makes the code easier to write automated tests (for a given set of inputs, you can test against the expected results).

**Naming**

Naming is fairly important for readability.  You variable names are mostly appropriate, but a few small things.  Your method `getUniqueProduct` doesn't return anything, which is misleading.  `productRetailer` is a collection of mappings, rather than a single product retailer.  Something like `productRetailerMappings` might be more descriptive.  `target` refers to a retailer, so `targetRetailer` would make this clearer, otherwise given the context it might be expected that it's the `targetProductId`.

**Consistency**

Modern IDE's can auto-format your code for you.  Inconsistencies suggest that either you don't use your IDE effectively, or that you lack attention to detail.  Both of these are things that interviewers are going to consider.  Two obvious things that stand out are sometimes there's `) {` and sometimes there's `){`.  A missing space may seem minor, but it is noticeable.  Another is blank line after at the top of the if block.  Sometimes you have one, sometimes you don't.

**To continue...or not**

> ```
> if(count[item]>1){
>     continue;
> }else
>     System.out.println(item);
> ```

It's almost always preferable to use `{}` around your `if`/`else` clauses.  Doing it for one side of an if, and not for the else, when they're both one-line is unnecessarily confusing.  The `else` is also redundant in this case, since if the `if` is triggered, the following code won't be executed anyway, you don't need the `else`.  Where possible you want to avoid introducing unnecessary nesting.  Since there's nothing else after the `println` that's executed, inverting the `if` would also make the code cleaner, since you wouldn't need the branch condition:

```
if(count[item]==1) {
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

**Constants can help readability**

You're using a two dimensional array, with a fixed size.  Have two constants, one for the ITEM_COUNT and one for the RETAILER_ID would help in understanding.  It's not obvious from this line:

> ```
> if(target == productRetailer[i][1]) {
> ```

What '1' is referring to (retailer or item).

Answer (score 0):

The exact time complexity of your algorithm is O(2*n) since it performs two sequential iterations on the array.

I do have a slightly better performing algorithm:

1. Sort the array by the first item in the 2nd dimension array (item number)
2. iterate over the sorted array looking for items that have exactly one line that has the requested target seller.

time complexity is O(n log n) + O(n)

Note:
streaming of arrays is possible with [Arrays.stream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-)

Edit:
Here is a complete solution with Java 8 streams:

```
private static void getUniqueProduct2(int[][] itemSeller, int target) {

    // map key is item, map value is list of 2nd dimension arrays that have this item
    Map<Integer, List<int[]>> map =
        Arrays.stream(itemSeller)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(arr -> arr[0]));

    // stream on map values, looking for lists with one list-item that belongs to target seller
    // build array of items that satisfy criteria
    int[] sellerExclusiveItems =
        map.values().stream()
            .filter(list -> list.size() == 1  &&  list.get(0)[1] == target)
            .mapToInt(list -> list.get(0)[0])
            .toArray();

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sellerExclusiveItems));
}
```

Comment: (Exact resource requirements analysis doesn't use "big-O". Asymptotic analysis ignores constant factors (like `2`).)

Comment: Are you suggest categorising or ordering when you suggest `sort `?

Comment: There is no such time complexity as O(2n). Because constants should be removed. Regarding the first approach, it doesn't seem better than the initial approach. The stream approach seems complicated to track but cleaner.

Comment: "doesn't seem better "? why? I explained why it has better performance (even if not better time complexity)

Comment: I guess the level of the complication of the stream approach is debatable and will differ with how much experience one has with Java 8 streams.

Comment: O(n log n) + O(n) Is still O(n log n). And it is worse than O(n) which Is same as O(2n) because there Is Always a constant of unspecified magnitude and we omit that constant for this exact reason. Can you explain what you mean that it has better performance even if time complexity Is worse? It may have better performance for some "small" n, but at some point and for any larger n, OP's code will perform better.